# Saving inside a loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to save in Matlab some matrices created at each iteration of a loop using names depending on the loop index `h`. More precisely, the code is

```
for h=1:4

   A=randn(2,1);
   B=randn(2,1);
   C=randn(2,1);

save(sprintf('data%d.mat',h),'-v7.3', 'A' , 'B', 'C')

end
```

for `h=3`,
I get the matrix `data3`, whose name depends on the loop index, containing the matrices `A,B,C`. I want to modify that line of code in a way such that `data3` containes `A3,B3,C3`.

Note: using `save(sprintf('data%d.mat',h), ['A' h], ['B' h], ['C' h] ,'-v7.3')` gives the error

```
Error using save
'A' is not a valid variable name.
```

Comment: Why do you want your variable names to be `A3`, `B3` and `C3` within `data3.mat`? Looking down the road, when you load that `mat`-file, how are you going to handle those changing variable names in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have used the correct signature for save method.

The correct signature for your job is:

```
save (filename, version, variables).
```

as opposed to `save(filename, variables, version)`. But because -v is parsed properly, it is okay.

*You can check if it is a valid variable name by using isvarname(string)*

This should do it:

```
  save(sprintf('data%d.mat',h), ['A' h], ['B' h], ['C' h] ,'-v7.3')
```

It would be better if you AVOIDED the -v7.3 as you are probably hardcoding the version-related settings for the MAT files. Try and use without the -v argument.

**BUT** your matrices are A, B, and C as opposed to A1, B1, C1,....etc. You can supply whatever variable name you like in save method, AS LONG AS THEY EXIST in your current workspace.

All you needed is a string concatenation which, in MATLAB, is similar to declaring a matrix e.g. `a = ['my' 'name' 'is' 'Bolshoi']`

Comment: It does not work, it tells me: Error using save
'A' is not a valid variable name.

Comment: @user3285148       paste your code execution statement and the error message in the original question. We need to say what you have done that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a [local function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) approach (or set the variable-renaming-function up in a separate script) to utilize the [`assignin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)-function.
The local function is required, because you need to create the new variable in the `caller` workspace. (Only `'caller'` and `'base'` are possible inputs for `assignin` - and `'base'` is the workspace outside the function).
In addition, you'll have to make use of the [`inputname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html)-function to get the actual variable name in your subfunction.

```
function test_func

for h=1:4

    A=randn(2,1);
    B=randn(2,1);
    C=randn(2,1);

    assignVar(A,h)
    assignVar(B,h)
    assignVar(C,h)

    save(sprintf('data%d.mat',h),'-v7.3', ['A' num2str(h)], ...
                                          ['B' num2str(h)], ...
                                          ['C' num2str(h)])

end

end

function assignVar(Q,h)
    assignin('caller',[inputname(1) num2str(h)],Q)
end
```

The function `assignVar` takes two arguments, `Q` and `h`. The latter is the loop counter, the former the variable you want to rename. You'll have to call this for each of your three variables. This will generate new variables in your workspace, called `A1` or `A2` or `A...` depending on the value of the loop counter `h`.
Now, when you call `save`, you can call these new variables with the same logic: `['A' num2str(h)]`. Note that you'll have to use `num2str` to combine the integer value of the loop counter and the string value of the variable.

---

However, carefully consider using this approach. Having variables called `A1`, `A2`, `A...` may prove to be a coding nightmare down the line when you load those workspace files and want to process the variables stored therein.